# How to detect bump mapping with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, bump-mapping

I have an image with bump mapping, like the image here (the rightmost one):

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_mapping#/media/File:Bump-map-demo-full.png]

I wonder if I can detect the bump mapping area with OpenCV. The image is a normal RGB image with no depth information. Any idea how to do the detection? Thank you very much!

Comment: It's impossible to tell whether bump mapping was used in general cases, since it's indistinguishable from a very detailed mesh (although in some cases low detail on the edges of the object is a giveaway).  [Here](https://github.com/detsikas/Texture-Segmentation-Using-Texture-Filters-and-OpenCV)'s a tutorial for a texture based segmentation if that's what you're looking for. Perhaps you can find an entropy threshold that will work in your case.

Comment: Thank you. The link is useful. I shall try the method.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the way the bump mapping is implemented, you may be able to detect it by comparing the local variation of luminance to the local variation of chrominance. If The luminance varies but the chrominance is stable for large areas, this could be indicative of bump mapping. Or it could be indicative of a high-polygon count irregular surface mesh...

Comment: Thank you, dvhamme, I shall test your method.